# How to open folder picker dialog in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing extension that has to support creating new, custom project templates (directory structure and few files) in a folder chosen by user. Is there any way to open folder picker dialog in vscode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now we can select folder using  window.showOpenDialog. Simply adjust options according to your need.

```
    const options: vscode.OpenDialogOptions = {
        canSelectMany: false,
        openLabel: 'Select',
        canSelectFiles: false,
        canSelectFolders: true
    };
   
   vscode.window.showOpenDialog(options).then(fileUri => {
       if (fileUri && fileUri[0]) {
           console.log('Selected file: ' + fileUri[0].fsPath);
       }
   });
```

Currently I'm working on Vs Code version: 1.51.0

Answer (score 16):

File dialogs were added in VSCode 1.17.  See [`window.showOpenDialog`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#window.showOpenDialog) and [`window.showSaveDialog`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#window.showSaveDialog).

They don't appear to choose a folder without a file, but they do allow multi-select and of course you can just take the path name of any chosen file.

```ts
const options: vscode.OpenDialogOptions = {
     canSelectMany: false,
     openLabel: 'Open',
     filters: {
        'Text files': ['txt'],
        'All files': ['*']
    }
};

vscode.window.showOpenDialog(options).then(fileUri => {
    if (fileUri && fileUri[0]) {
        console.log('Selected file: ' + fileUri[0].fsPath);
    }
});
```

Note you may need to update your `package.json` file to get access to this new API.

```json
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.17.0"
},
```